# jQuery is not defined in RichFaces scripts

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I've been migrating aplication from EJB to JSF + Spring and doing this, I updated RichFaces from 3.3.1 to 4.1.0.
Now I'm struggling with following problem, that the console in chrome shows

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

in RichFaces scripts like richfaces-event.js, popupPanel.js.
I know that in header of the html file, including of the jQuery file should be first, but I've looked into the former application and this scripts are also included there before jQuery and no errors appear. What's more, I don't now how I could change this, because these scripts are added implicitly by having:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
```

How can I fix this problem?

```
<f:view contentType="text/html" locale="#{localeSelector.language}">
<h:head>
    <title>#{messages['news.title']}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>

</h:head>


<h:body>
    <h:outputScript name="jquery.js" library="js" target="head" />
    <div id="container">
            </div>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

---

The problem here is not lightbox but RichFaces.The html code generated is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ESA/javax.faces.resource/richfaces-event.js.xhtml">        </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ESA/javax.faces.resource/popupPanel.js.xhtmlln=org.richfaces"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ESA/javax.faces.resource/popupPanelBorders.js.xhtml?ln=org.richfaces"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ESA/javax.faces.resource/popupPanelSizer.js.xhtml?ln=org.richfaces"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ESA/javax.faces.resource/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ESA/javax.faces.resource/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js.xhtml?ln=js"></script>
```

But is the application I'm migrating, the code is the same and console does not show any errors

Comment: Can you show the rest of your file? Do you import jQuery directly? Do you use `<h:head>`? Did you removed the previous libraries from `/lib` folder?

Comment: Code added.
As you see, I used `<h:head>` tag and it is still not working.
The `/lib` folder was cleared and no previous libraries appear there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load your JavaScript libraries in the right order. If you see the source of the rendered page you will see that `jQuery` is loaded in second or not at all because of the `library="js"`.

Modify the inclusion like that :

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputScript name="jquery.js" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js" />
</h:head>
```

**Note :**

The `jQuery` used will come from RichFaces, you wont be able to use the `$` descriptor. You will need to use `jQuery("your-selector")...` instead. You will also need to put the LightBox library in `<web-root>/resources/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js` so it will be found.

Comment: But in the generated html code the RichFaces scripts are before jQuery and LightBox and the console shows that they're the problem, not LightBox

Comment: @Nav the generated code is from your migrated version or old one? ie : RichFaces 3.3 or RichFaces 4.1

Comment: Both generated htmls ( former and new one ) have the same sequence of scripts. First appear the RichFaces scripts, to be exact: `richfaces-event.js, popupPanel.js, popupPanelBorders.js, popupPanelSizer.js`. The old one was with 3.3.1 and the new one is with 4.1

Comment: @Nav not sure to understand, your update in your question (scripts includes) is from version on RF 3.3 or RF 4.1? You should include the output of the other version if they are different.

Comment: But that's the point that both .xhtml files are the same, because I just copied the file from the former application to the new one and changed maven artifact to RichFaces 4.1. The output of both versions is the same.